# $_GET['q'] for all entities

Tags: 7, entities

I have this code.

```
     if ($_GET['q'] == 'entity/bundle'){ 
        unset($css[drupal_get_path('module', 'system') . '/system.base.css']);
 }
```

Which I use in template.php to unset css on certain pages, but I want to have code (in this case unset css) to run on all entity pages for example entity/bundle/1, entity/bundle/2, entity/bundle/3. How can I get this to apply to all entity pages. I need something like entity/bundle/% or entity/bundle/* or maybe there is another way.

Comment: For one thing, you should probably be adding the CSS to the pages you need, not taking them off the ones you don't. Of course there are always edge cases I guess. As for doing what you asked, use a `hook_preprocess_entity`. This will allow you to act on all entities and use the machine name, title etc of the entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Context add assets seems to be a good solution for this https://www.drupal.org/project/context_addassets